# Get files from VM in recovery mode

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04

I've had many problems that I cannot seem to solve in my VM, and I've decided to just backup the important files from the guest (ubuntu) to the host (Windows 10) and reinstall.

I can access the terminal via recovery mode, but I cannot start the VM normally.

I had a shared folder between the host and guest, but ls -a does not show it.

How can I do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, could you please point me at some resource where that is explained? I'm a bit of a newbie in this and what you just said wen a bit over my head.

Comment: Found a solution, in case someone has the same problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/37767/how-to-access-a-usb-flash-drive-from-the-terminal